# How do I add an address search to my Google Map Fusion Layer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I've got a embedded Google Map in a website that has a Fusion Table Layer and I was wondering how I add an address search to this map that will locate to the searched area though still have my Fusion Layer on it so I can retrieve data for that area.

I have looked at the Google Maps Places API and I managed to implement the Places Search Box: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

However, when I search a place using this, it goes to the location as a standard google map and my fusion layer is lost.

I believe this is something to do with when it creates a new map after the submitted search but I don't know how to edit this to redraw my fusion layer.

Also, I would prefer to use my own search box that wasn't on top of the map, so I can position it elsewhere on the page. Is this possible?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_collection-map2e_FT.html)?  Or [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_geocoder_PointInPolygon.html)? Or [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_circle_geocode_gviz.html)? The details will depend on your specific FusionTable.  They all use the Geocoder to get the coordinates of the address and query the table using the coordinates.

Comment: Yes!! Pretty much the exact same as that! 
I'll be searching by addresses and postcodes and just need it to automatically relocate to the searched area with the fusion layer and data still there!

Comment: A combination of the second and third links you posted are ideally what I am trying to accomplish.